# Git push takes a lot of time due to increase in number of objects

Tags: git, android-studio, gerrit

Whenever I push changes to git repo, the writing objects phase takes a lot of time. There are many duplicate issues related to this but most of them are due to being stuck in uploading the objects which is not the issue in my case.

`Writing objects:  87% (50271/57775), 130.81 MiB | 362.00 KiB/s`

**57775** <-- This value keeps increasing in my subsequent pushes.
So every push takes a lot of time and amending them is even more frustrating.

I tried running `git gc` as well but didn't fix the issue I have.

I am not sure how to fix this.
Any idea?

**Edit:** Even for a very small change in 1 file, I will have to undergo this long upload delay.

Comment: How many objects have you added by adding new commits? Are you pushing via the smart protocols? And (perhaps most important) are you using shallow clones?

Comment: That's a big repo with lots of stuff it in! I would check to make sure you're not accidentally committing something like the `node_modules` directory or some other local-install cache? (There are legitimate use cases for big repos with lots of files, don't get me wrong, but there are also accidental ones to avoid...)

Comment: @torek Even for a very small change in 1 file, I will have to undergo this long upload delay. The push is initiated by android-studio so yes it should be following the standard protocols. No not using shallow clones.

Comment: Git's not seeing a very small change in one file, that's a lot of changes being pushed. `git diff-tree @{u} @ | awk '{print $4,$6} | git cat-file --batch-check=$'%(objectsize)\t%(rest)'` to get a quick look at what's really changed and how big it is.

Comment: When you fetch first (*not* pull) and then push, is the push still large? And when you make another commit on top of one that you have just pushed, is that second push also slow?

Comment: @jthill thanks for that script i wanted to know what the hell is getting written, i haven't tried yet but definitely will check.

Comment: @j6t fetch and push is large, and pushing the next commit on top of previous one is larger and hence slower.

Comment: Show how you invoke`git fetch` and show its complete output, some for a push. Do you have a remote configured? A shot in the dark: you are missing a configured fetch refspec.